# Two hash tables with same key vs a combined hash

Tags: c++, hash, stl, hashtable, unordered-map

I'm wondering which implementations (below) will give me a better performance in time and space. Let's say I have the following directory structure.

```
/dir1
    OWN={root,usr}
/dir2
    DEP={dir1}
    OWN={usr}
```

I one-time walk through all direcories from "./" where each directory has an owner file and may have a dependency file. I read their content and build hash table(s).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    unordered_map<string, vector<string>> dir_ownerss;
    // /dir1 --> [root, usr]
    // /dir2 --> [usr]
    unordered_map<string, vector<string>> dir_dependenciess;
    // /dir1 --> [dir2]

    unordered_map<string, vector<vector<string>>> dir_owners_and_dependenciess;
    // /dir1 --> [ [/dir1, root, usr] [/dir2, usr] ]
    // /dir2 --> [ [/dir2, usr] ]

    return 0;
}
```

Later in this program, I will do some look-up or find() operations to check ownership and dependencies. Since hash operation averagely are O(1), order wise I do not see a difference. One requires two find() call, the other one needs one call but maybe not preferred because of hashing, space,... Also, design wise, there's no limit.

Comment: Please make your effort into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does the second type-parameter of `dir_owners_and_dependencies` really need to be a vector?  It sounds like these vectors will always contain exactly two items (one vector-of-owners and one vector-of-dependencies), in which case storing the vectors inside a vector is overkill; you could use a `tuple`, an array, or a class/struct (with two vectors in it) instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Will do. It is more like a CS question than programming. But C++ is always a good choice.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes. To contain different owners-and-deps distinctly for later use. A dir might depends on many other dirs.

Comment: @KyleDickson It's still not minimal, complete and verifiable. Try copying your own code from here and compile it.

Comment: @KyleDickson Yes, but all of those other dirs can be stored in the same vector, correct?  So you for each dir you just need one vector of owners and one vector of other-dirs (i.e. you don't ever need three or more vectors per dir)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Since I'm storying the dirs name and owner both, I'd not be able to extract the one dep with it's owner. A dir may have multiple owners. What you are saying looks like this: `/dir1 --> [ /dir1, root, usr, dir2, usr ]` If understood correctly. Each der in dep is followed by it's owners.

Comment: @KyleDickson I'm getting the feelintg that you are making things harder than they need to be. What's the purpose?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm here for resolving the same confusion. I thought maybe combining two hashes into one, may get me better performance in terms of time and space. I

Comment: Ok, I may have misinterpreted your explaination ... or the question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. Multiple O(1) lookups is going to be more expensive than a single O(1) lookup. It also takes more time to update multiple maps when you add or remove an item.
2. There is a certain amount of overhead storing the keys and such for a map. With a single map, you're paying that overhead once. With multiple maps, you pay it multiple times.

Granted, it's all O(1) for lookup and O(n) for memory, but two maps takes twice as much memory. Twice as many lookups takes twice as much time.

I think you'd be better off by using a single map that has a class as its value. (Please pardon the syntax; C++ isn't something I work with every day.)

```
class directory {
    vector<string> owners;
    vector<string> dependencies;
}
```

And then your map becomes:

```
unordered_map<string, directory> directories;
```

So if you want to know something about a particular directory, you look that directory up in the map. You have immediate access to the owners and the dependencies. There's no reason to have a separate map for each different attribute.

Another benefit of using a single map that stores a class: it simplifies your code. And that's always a good thing.

Comment: Sure. I'm more interested in knowing the performance than implementation. Any point on that you want to share?